# Jquery Cycle2 slideshow - load images from server, ASP .NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, slideshow, jquery-cycle2

I'm trying to use Cycle2 slideshow plugin with ASP .NET.
Images are dynamically loading from server.

Slideshow doesn't work and images are loaded/shown one after the other in the page but when I check the page html in chrome inspect element, html looks fine.

I just wont to know how to load images from server side(dynamically) to the slideshow.

Here is my HTML Code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#imageUrls").load("LoadImages.aspx", function() {
        $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle();
      });
    })
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="imageUrls" class="cycle-slideshow"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the server response

```
<img src="http://example.com/images/1.jpg">
<img src="http://example.com/images/1.jpg">
```

This is how it's looks in chrome inspect element and works fine when I run this code in browser.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="cycle-slideshow">
    <img src="http://example.com/images/1.jpg">
    <img src="http://example.com/images/2.jpg">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

How to create a slide show with dynamic image loading using ASP .NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the mistake.
Corrected code.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#imageUrls").load("ImageLoad.aspx", function() {
        $('#imageUrls').cycle();
      });
    })
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="imageUrls"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Shouldn't use class="cycle-slideshow" which automatically initialize a slide show.

> Cycle2 slideshows can be automatically initialized simply by adding
>   the classname cycle-slideshow to your slideshow container element.

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" ...
```

> Cycle2 will automatically find and
>   initialize a slideshow for any element that contains this classname.
>   If you do not want this behavior then do not add the cycle-slideshow
>   class to your slideshow and instead initalize the slideshow
>   programmatically by invoking the cycle method on the slideshow
>   container element:

$( '.mySlideshows' ).cycle();

> Auto-initialization is not supported for
>   slideshows that are added to the DOM after jQuery's ready event has
>   fired. In this case you will need to programatically initialize your
>   slideshow by invoking the cycle method as shown above. You do not need
>   to qualify your selector to the part of the DOM that has been updated
>   as Cycle2 will not re-initialize a running slideshow if you invoke
>   cycle on it more than once. So it is perfectly safe to run the code
>   above multiple times without having to worry about slideshows that are
>   already running.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/